# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'endswith', django , python

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-admin, image-uploading

My project structure is something like:

- /blog1   ***(Name of project)***

  - /blog1/media/blog1/media
  - /blog  ***(Name of app)***

    - /blog/media
    - /static
    - /media
  - /static/templates

I have uploaded a photo through django-admin panel , but when i view the image through the view page source from browser , it shows an error :

```
AttributeError at /blog/view/blog1/media/high-tech-snapshot_3.jpg
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

Traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/view/blog1/media/high-tech-snapshot_3.jpg

Django Version: 1.6.5
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'blog',
'embed_video')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
112.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/static.py" in serve
49.     fullpath = os.path.join(document_root, newpath)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py" in join
77.         elif path == '' or path.endswith('/'):

Exception Type: AttributeError at /blog/view/blog1/media/high-tech-snapshot_3.jpg
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

Here are my directories in settings.py :

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/blog1/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'media')
```

Here are my models :

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import permalink
from embed_video.fields import EmbedVideoField

class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    body = models.TextField()
    posted = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, auto_now_add=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey('blog.Category')
    video = EmbedVideoField( blank=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="blog1/media/", blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % self.title

    @permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('view_blog_post', None, { 'slug': self.slug })
```

Here is my views.py:

```
def index(request):
    return render_to_response('index.html', {
        'categories': Category.objects.all(),
        'posts': Blog.objects.all()[:6]
        })

def view_post(request, slug):   
    return render_to_response('view_post.html', {
        'post': get_object_or_404(Blog, slug=slug)

    })
```

My admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from blog.models import Blog
from embed_video.admin import AdminVideoMixin

class BlogAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    exclude = ['posted']
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}

    admin.site.register(Blog, BlogAdmin)
```

my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
import os 
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
# Examples:
# url(r'^$', 'blog1.views.home', name='home'),
# url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

url(r'^$', 'blog.views.index'),

url(
r'^blog/view/(?P<slug>[^\.]+).html', 
'blog.views.view_post', 
name='view_blog_post'),

url(r'^About/$', 'blog.views.about', name='about'),

url(
r'^blog/category/(?P<slug>[^\.]+).html', 
'blog.views.view_category', 
name='view_blog_category'),


url(r'^blog/view/blog1/media/(.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',name ='media_url'),
)
```

and my view_post.html:

```
{% block content %}
<h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
<p>{{ post.body }}</p>
<img src="{{ post.photo }}"/>
 {% endblock %}
```

I am sure i am doing some silly mistake , if anyone knows please help me .

***Thanks in advance, and sorry for bad naming of directories , i am new to django and don't know how to list directories in right way.***

Comment: Please include the full traceback of the exception.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have updated the details, you can see that now .

Comment: Please post the actual urls.py, not random half-lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved similar problem by add this in `settings.py`

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

and also maybe you need to run command

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Hope this helps

Comment: yeah, for me it was a missing `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`